# Python Loops result not understanding

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, range

Can anyone please help explain what the hell is going on with this code and why it is printing 'Hello Hi' two times every time?[Questionable Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLb02.png)

Comment: Please include code and results as text, not as an image.

Comment: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/for_loop_range/

Comment: Hi, welcome!  Please, read the following and adjust your question accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Because the length of `y` is `2`. If you iterate the `y` it will definitely print 2 times.

Comment: Please also add to your question what you expected to get as output instead.

Comment: your ```y``` is a list with 2 elements. Then, "for each x in y", you print ```y``` (which is the list with 2 elements, "hello" and "hi").
Basically, what the code is doing in that ```for``` is giving ```x``` the value of the first element of the list, "Hello", then you print the list ```y = ["Hello", "Hi"]```. After it gives ```x``` the second value of the list, "Hi", then you print the list again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submitted code is doing 2 things. First, in :

```
for x in range(0,4):
    print(x)
```

The code is iterating through (0,1,2,3), and printing its current value. This seems to be intended.

Then, within this loop, in:

```
    for x in y:
        print(y)
```

The code is iterating through the elements of y, which is ["Hello", "Hi"], and printing y back each time. So the loop iterates twice, and each time it prints out all of y, so it prints ["Hello", "Hi"].

Your question leads me to believe that you are trying to produce code that prints the elements of y seperately, and so something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
y = ["Hello", "Hi"]
for i in range(0,4):
    print(i)
    for j in y:
        print(j)
```

This will output:

```
0
Hello
Hi
1
Hello
Hi
2
Hello
Hi
3
Hello
Hi
```